# Best Practices for monitoring email server?

Tags: email, exchange, monitoring

We manage about 50 exchange servers. What do you guys use to monitor that the server is working properly (email flow, latency, etc.)?

Tips? suggestions?

Comment: This is very open-ended and discussion oriented. Because of this, it's off-topic. That said, plenty of tools exist that can do this. Nagios/OpsView, SCOM, Orion, Cacti all come to mind.

Comment: I could see this being a canonical question for monitoring Exchange environments... UPVOTE.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to succesfully use Zenoss Core to do this for a five server Exchange environment. You cannot foresee every failure occurrence though here's what I did do:

Per Server Ping/Interface monitoring

Per Server event log monitoring

Per Server Service Monitoring

Using WMI:

Collected statistics on mailboxes, queues, etc.

Using the CheckMail Zenpack:
This ZenPack extended the system to generating an e-mail, sending it via a specific SMTP server, sending it out to a public address, retrieving and replying to said mail, and measuring how long that round trip took.

This is kind of open ended, but there are options out there. I would think if you're doing any clustering it might get more complicated by Exchange 2010 seems to be pushing people to application level redundancy instead of system redundancy so maybe that gets easier.

Comment: Have you tried using a round-trip email monitor (if you not sure what that is do a google seach). It seems like the most effective tool but im just looking for the right one. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: Also not sure why im not getting email updates about this forum. I didnt know you posted an answer until i logged back in